# Error during php artisan sail:install - Repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm trying to set up a Laravel application using Laravel Sail. During the installation process, when running the command `php artisan sail:install`, I encountered an error related to the Ubuntu repositories. Here is the specific error message I received:

```
   omar@Omar:~/www/full-version$ php artisan sail:install
    
    Which services would you like to install? [mysql]:
      [0] mysql
      [1] pgsql
      [2] mariadb
      [3] redis
      [4] memcached
      [5] meilisearch
      [6] minio
      [7] mailpit
      [8] selenium
      [9] soketi
     > 0
    
    Sail scaffolding installed successfully.
    [+] Running 1/1
     ✔ mysql Pulled                                                                                                                                                                                    2.3s 
    Sail images installed successfully.
    [+] Building 5.3s (8/15)                                                                                                                                                                                
     => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
     => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
     => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                               0.0s
     => => transferring dockerfile: 2.44kB                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
     => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:21.04                                                                                                                                    2.0s
     => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:21.04@sha256:ba394fabd516b39ccf8597ec656a9ddd7d0a2688ed8cb373ca7ac9b6fe67848f                                                                            0.0s
     => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
     => => transferring context: 99B                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
     => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
     => CACHED [ 3/11] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezone                                                                                                  0.0s
     => ERROR [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && ch  3.2s
    ------
     > [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev        php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd        php8.1-curl        php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring        php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap        php8.1-intl php8.1-readline        php8.1-ldap        php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole        php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*:
    #0 1.485 Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
    #0 1.493 Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security InRelease
    #0 1.823 Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates InRelease
    #0 1.834 Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release
    #0 1.834   404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
    #0 2.154 Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
    #0 2.490 Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release
    #0 2.490   404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
    #0 2.813 Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release
    #0 2.813   404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
    #0 3.154 Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release
    #0 3.154   404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.36 80]
    #0 3.164 Reading package lists...
    #0 3.183 E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
    #0 3.184 E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
    #0 3.184 E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
    #0 3.184 E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
    ------
    failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo \"disable-ipv6\" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E5267A6C     && apt-key adv --homedir ~/.gnupg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys C300EE8C     && echo \"deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu hirsute main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev        php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd        php8.1-curl        php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring        php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap        php8.1-intl php8.1-readline        php8.1-ldap        php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole        php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug     && php -r \"readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');\" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -     && echo \"deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main\" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Comment: Could you copy paste it again? it has no spaces or new lines, it is honestly very unreadable. Could you also share if you have changed anything from a Dockerfile?

Comment: Start breaking up your `&&` statements into separate  commands. We cannot tell your error is actually related to php or not

Comment: I am so sorry I did it by mistake